# Where does Mac OS X store contacts in my Address Book?

Tags: contacts

Where does Mac OS X store contacts in my Address Book? Has this changed from Snow Leopard to Lion?

Comment: I think it's at `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Metadata`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The path is `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/` on both Snow Leopard and Lion.

Note that you can't see the Library in your home folder (as it is hidden by default). You can type in `chflags nohidden ~/Library` in Terminal to make it appear permanently, or hold down <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> while in the "Go" menu of Finder.

Answer (score 1):

> On SL, it's in
>
> - ~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Metadata
>
> I can't answer for Lion.

Lion is the same....

In High Sierra, its in ~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources/

Comment: @bckbck: Simul-typing. Great minds run in the same direction I guess. Make your comment an answer.  I'll yield....

Comment: Note that ~/Library is hidden by default in Lion. You can unhide it with a Terminal command, or you can go to it in Finder by holding down the Option/Alt key and selecting the Go menu in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience of just trying to recover those files with TimeMachine in Mavericks, the location in Mavericks appears to be incorrect.

Comment: Where is the correct location?

Answer (score -3):

OSX 10.9.1 go to Contacts.app, highlight the contact(s) select more than one with the shift key, press DELETE then OK

Comment: How does this show where they're stored?